# How to select data between two special characters? python

Tags: python, regex

I have a file `abcd.txt` containing:

```
"""    
hello,123 [1231,12312]1231231    
hello, world[3r45t,3242]6542    
123 213 135    
4234 gdfg gfd 32   
sd23 234 sdf 23    
hi, hello[234,23423]561    
hello, hi[123,123]985   
"""
```

I want to print the string which is after the second ',' character till the ']'.
My output should be:

```
12312
3242
23423
123
```

I tried this:

```
def select(self):
        file = open('gis.dat')
        list1 = []
        for line in file:
            line = line.strip()
            if re.search('[a-zA-Z]',line):
                list1.append(line.partition(',')[-1].rpartition(']')[0])
        return list1
```

Comment: `3242`   doesn't come after 2 commas.

Comment: sorry i made a mistake over there. I changed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use:

```
import re
for line in open("abcd.txt"):
    match = re.findall(r".*?,.*?,(\d+)", line)
    if match:
        print match[0]
```

---

Output:

```
12312
3242
23423
123
```